# One page SSRS report for each distinct value of table

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create an SSRS report which will display various objects (charts, tablix ...).
This report must display data refering to a distinct value of a table.
This is like a group but for all objects of my report.

Do you know how to do that ? I thinked about creating a list or a table and insert objects in it but a list or tablix could only have one dataset and I have many.

Could you suggest solution ?

Thanks

Comment: can i know how many datasets you are using?

Comment: Ok put list in main report with one dataset and use 4 sub reports for other datasets... will that work for you

Comment: Hi souds great, I'll test it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Put list in main report with one dataset and use 4 sub reports for other datasets...